# amp config test site giving error

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, civicrm-buildkit

I am new to buildkit, I tried running amp config and it looks like the amp test works properly after following the buildkit documentation. It said 'received expected response' in the terminal when I ran amp test but localhost:7979 gives me an error:

> Error: Expected GET or POST value 'exampleData=foozball' Error: Failed to write /Users/varshanayanar/.amp/canary/data/IFZK6GOETKf28HsBKdBng9FcQs1ppSGz/example.txt Error: Failed to remove /Users/varshanayanar/.amp/canary/data/IFZK6GOETKf28HsBKdBng9FcQs1ppSGz/example.txt.

I am running this on a Mac. Below are the amp config details:

```
db_type:mysql_dsn ,   
mysql_dsn : mysql://root:root@localhost:8889 ,  
perm_type:worldwritable,     
hosts type:file,   
httpd_type :apache24,   
httpd_visibility:local,   
httpd_restart_command : /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl graceful,
```

I have also added IncludeOptional to the Apache configuration file. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean if you access localhost:7979 in your browser? I think that's expected, this port is just for amp testing in the specific way that amp tests by sending data. I get the same on my Mac.

Are you trying to access a site that you set up with buildkit? I believe it is set up by default on port 80. You can check in home/.amp/apache.d/ where there will be a configuration file. For some reason, I've had trouble accessing mine in Chrome (I get the default Apache page), but it works in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to access the wordpress site setup with buildkit.I get the default apache page (It Works!)for localhost in both chrome and firefox

Comment: http://my-wp-civi539.localhost  -This is taking me to the Default apache page.I have wp folder installed inside the build folder but donot know how to access this wp site

Comment: Actually, I had that issue too.
I added Listen 127.0.0.1:80 (or whatever the port is) to the top of the conf file for the buildkit site in home/.amp/apache.d, then it worked.

Then restart Apache (sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl graceful)

Comment: Unfortunately,that didn't work for me. There are 3 conf files and localhost_7979.conf has Listen 127.0.0.1:7979.Other files are related to the WP sites and Tried changing that too and it didn't work for some reason. New error came up in terminal  :  Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8899

Comment: Not sure what that means. This might be a good question to take to CiviCRM chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/